# Calculating Application's memory consumption using JMX

Tags: notifications, jmx

I want to write a memory monitoring and notification utility that monitors specific application in JVM. To be clear I am not interested in JVM memory consumption rather I want to monitor my application memory alone, and want to get notified (by email) when ever the memory exceeds certain levels.

MemoryMxBean deals with JVM memory I guess.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sigar](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar). It has a Java based API for gathering information about the native OS memory usage, as well as about individual processes. It will be fairly straight forward to create a JMX MBean that uses Sigar to expose this data.

//Nicholas